# rails csv, array shows no data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using csv to export data. I am dynamically populating the fields and in order to do so i have added loop in to csv:

```
csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << [
  @userHeaders.each do |user|
    "#{user.name}"
  end
  ]
end
```

but this returns some thing like this: `[#<User >, #<User >, #<User >, #<User >]`

but when i tried to inspect the value after assigning it to a variable, it displays all the names that have been passed.

```
name = "#{user.name}"
puts name.inspect  # (this diaplays all the names)
```

is there any format to display the data while looping inside csv?

please guide with answer
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try just using the `map` (aka `collect`) method of your array:

```
csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << @userHeaders.map { |user| user.name }
end
```

Comment: Thanks it works great. i have one more case where data is not displaying properly, while displaying data in EXcel, it show like this ["jack","Tom","Kevin"] in a colunm. this is not returning as separate column. this is code i used just adding two more fields before loop  csv << [
        "Country","State",
         @userHeaders.map { |user| user.name },
        
        ]

Comment: You probably want to use `csv << ["Country", "State"] + @userHeaders.map { |user| user.name }` instead.